# VB.NET linq extension methods such as ToList not working with generics

Tags: vb.net, linq

In a VB.NET class file, I'm trying to use extension methods such as ToList(), where the generic parameter is populated with what I know to be the subclass, in this context.

```
Dim specificOrders = request.Orders _
.Where(Function(x) x.GetType().Equals(GetType(SpecificOrderType))) _
.ToList(Of SpecificOrderType)()
```

However, I'm getting the error message "extension method is not generic or has no type parameters available". Any ideas as to why this is?
This method should be in the System.Linq namespace - I have it open and referenced in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use `Where` to filter by type. That's what the `OfType` method is for. It filters and casts:

```
Dim specificOrders = request.Orders.
                             OfType(Of SpecificOrderType)().
                             ToList()
```

In that case, `OfType` returns an `IEnumerable(Of SpecificOrderType)` and calling `ToList` on that returns a `List(Of SpecificOrderType)`.  That's how `ToList` works.  It simply create a `List(Of T)` with the same generic type as the `IEnumerable(Of T)` that it's called on.

If you were going to use `Where`, you would use `Cast` to go from the base type to `SpecificOrderType`:

```
Dim specificOrders = request.Orders.
                             Where(Function(x) x.GetType().Equals(GetType(SpecificOrderType))).
                             Cast(Of SpecificOrderType)().
                             ToList()
```

One point to note about `OfType` is that it will match any item that can be cast as the specified type. That is usually what you want and probably the result that your original code would produce but it's worth noting that any item that was of a type that inherited `SpecificOrderType` would be excluded by your original code but included using `OfType`.

Answer (score 0):

`ToList()` can not have type arguments, because that method is not generic.

So just use `ToList()`

```
 Dim suborders = orders _
                 .Where(Function(x) x.GetType().Equals(GetType(nonspecificOrder))) _
                 .ToList()
```

Try below example.

```
'Order class    
Public Class order

End Class

'specificOrder class    
 Public Class specificOrder
        Inherits order


 End Class

'nonspecificOrder class
 Public Class nonspecificOrder
        Inherits order


 End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim orders As List(Of order) = New List(Of [order])

Dim s1 As specificOrder = New specificOrder()
Dim s2 As specificOrder = New specificOrder()
Dim s3 As specificOrder = New specificOrder()
Dim s4 As specificOrder = New specificOrder()
Dim s5 As nonspecificOrder = New nonspecificOrder()
Dim s6 As nonspecificOrder = New nonspecificOrder()

orders.Add(DirectCast(s1, order))
orders.Add(DirectCast(s2, order))
orders.Add(DirectCast(s3, order))
orders.Add(DirectCast(s4, order))
orders.Add(DirectCast(s5, order))
orders.Add(DirectCast(s6, order))


 Dim suborders = orders _
                .Where(Function(x) x.GetType().Equals(GetType(nonspecificOrder))) _
                 .ToList()
```

Now the two "nonspecificOrder" type objects are returned.

Comment: I needed the strongly typed object as a result, so I called Select(Function(x) DirectCast(x, specific)) after the Where call. This works, but I was wondering if there was a shorter/more expressive way to do the same thing.